# Is the Prokofiev ballet Romeo and Juliet performed with narration?

Tags: dance

It seems like an obvious question, but neither the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_and_Juliet_(Prokofiev)), nor the [IMSLP page](https://imslp.org/wiki/Romeo_and_Juliet_(ballet),_Op.64_(Prokofiev,_Sergey)), will tell me if this ballet is performed with narration, or if ballet is entirely instrumental.

If performed with narration, what Russian translation/narration was used?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about music practice or theory as outlined in the help center.

Comment: Is there a reason why it would be produced differently from all other ballet? Also this question is probably more appropriate for https//:musicfans.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ToddWilcox This question is directly about how a musical work is performed in practice, so how is it off-topic?

Comment: @RosieF The question is about someone else would perform it, not how the one asking the question is meant to perform it. Also, narration is not music. Overall, the question seems to be asked from the point of view of a listener of music, not a performer or producer of music.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  While I agree that ballets never (or almost never) have narrators, to claim that narration isn't part of music is wrong.   Peter and the Wolf is the obvious example.

Comment: If the full score doesn't have a narration line, then there is no narration.  Where would you expect to find the spoken text if not in the score?

Comment: Thank you Carl for the answer. I have performed Peter and the Wolf before. (abridged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prokofiev almost certainly didn't intend "Romeo and Juliet" to be performed with narration because there is no narration in the score.
It's not usual for ballets to be performed with a narration, although it might be done in certain cases, e.g. for educational purposes.

Comment: I thought this (and I did look at the score to check), but it just seemed so weird to me that such a play like Romeo and Juliet, which is incredible literature, could be done without all the language. And on top of that Prokofiev changed the ending!

Comment: @ShawnLandden  **all** ballets present their story through the combo of music and physical expression.  You might call it the origin of mime :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The ancient Greeks developed mime. Ballet didn't originate until the 15th century